# Facing issue in Socket io, receiving 2 responses for a single data requested

Tags: javascript, reactjs, socket.io, setinterval

So, I'm building a react project which displays a number, let's say Revenue.
The value of this revenue is stored in a stateful object like this: revenue = {old:0, new:0}

Now I have set up a socket connection on my client and server.

server:

```
io.on("connection", async (socket) => {
  masterData[socket.id] = [];
  const sockets = await io.fetchSockets();

  socket.on("data", async (msg) => {
    socket.join(msg.name);

    if (msg.type === "client") {
      let data = await fetchRev(msg.name, msg.startDate, msg.endDate)
      io.to(msg.name).emit("data_received", data);
    }

    else if(msg.type === "publisher") {
      let data = await fetchRevByPub(msg.name, msg.startDate, msg.endDate)
      io.to(msg.name).emit("data_received", data);
    }

    else {
      io.to(msg.name).emit("data_received", {error: "wrong typeofUser"});
    }
  })
```

and on client, there are some conditions:

1. I want to request data every 10 seconds (to update revenue)
2. There is an option for user to change date, and as soon as the date is changed, a new request should be sent
3. The revenue that is being displayed to the user should look like as if the number is counting up. For that purpose, I have used react-countup module that evenly increases the revenue from 'old' to 'new' value

Here, 'new' value will be the one received from socket every 10 secs and 'old' value is the value previously stored in 'new'

In order to fulfill these conditions, I have written the socket code inside a useEffect:

```
const [DATE, setDATE] = useState({
    startDate: "",
    endDate: "",
    client: "",
  });
const intervalRef = useRef(null);

 useEffect(() => {
    if (DATE["startDate"] !== "" && DATE["endDate"] !== "") {
      let socket = io(process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL, {
        transports: ["websocket"],
      });

      const getData = () => {
        const start = DATE["startDate"],
        let end = DATE["endDate"];

        socket.emit("data", {
          name: clientName,
          startDate: start,
          endDate: end,
          type: userType,
        });
      };
      getData();
      intervalRef.current = setInterval(() => {
        getData();
      }, 10000);

      socket.on("data_received", (msg) => calcData(msg));

      return () => {
        socket.off("data_received");
        clearInterval(intervalRef.current);
      };
    }
  }, [DATE]);
```

calcData is a function that processes the data received and populate revenue accordingly.

Now the issue I'm facing is, every once in a while, as the value in revenue is changing (increasing) steadily, out of the blue I'll start receiving 2 responses in the duration of these 10 secs.
Due to which, the revenue number starts counting up and due to the new response goes down and up and down...

I'll try using an example, initially startDate is 1 Mar and endDate is 10 Mar for which I receive revenue as 100. Now every 10 secs this revenue is increasing in the range of 10.

```
1st 10 secs: old: 0, new: 100
next 10 secs: old: 100, new: 110
next 10 secs: old: 110, new: 120
.
.
.
```

Then I decide to change the date, startDate = 1 Mar and endDate = 30 Mar for which I receive the revenue as 2000 and it increases in the range of 500

```
1st 10 secs: old: 0, new: 2000
next 10 secs: old: 2000, new: 2500
next 10 secs: old: 2500, new: 3000
.
.
.
```

To tell my issue using this example, in between my revenue being increased from 2000 to 2500 to 3000, it will start somthing like this

```
1st 10 secs: 
old: 2000, new: 2500      4th second
old: 2500, new: 100          8th second
next 10 secs: 
old: 100, new: 3000      14th second
old: 3000, new: 110        18th second
.
.
.
```

Due to which, the counting up in revenue go absolutely crazy.

The reasons I suspect for this are:

1. setInterval going out of sync
2. setInterval not clearing properly (I have verified this, most probably it's not the case)
3. socket connection is somehow getting mixed up within the devices connected to the same server (I suspect this because sometimes the data on my screen goes haywire if I change the date in another device)

Now this might appear to be a little confusing and too much text, but I'm willing to provide more info if need be. Please help me out folks...

and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

So I found out the solution on my own, was too lazy to post it here. But, you gotta provide if you're willing to take

The issue was a tiny foundational bug in creating socket room

My initial code was:

```
socket.on("data", async (msg) => {

    socket.join(msg.name);
    .
    .
```

here the socket room is being created on the basis of msg.name, which is not unique. Thus, every time user sends requests with the same msg.name, a little mess is created on socket's part since both the user's with different requirements are connected to the same socket room

To avoid this, I've used socket.id which is a unique id created for every separate instance

```
socket.on("data", async (msg) => {

    socket.join(socket.id);
    .
    .
```

And this solved the problem LOL...